# Channels and entries structure on site with deep hierarchy

Tags: playa, channel, structure, entries, content-elements

I'm trying to wrap my head around the most efficient way to set up entries in EE for my site structure. This is my first EE build, coming from a Wordpress background and I'm looking for opinions on how a more experienced EE dev would approach setting up my site's structure.

The site can be defined as an e-catalog, no e-commerce functionality is present but the site is largely based off the product views. I am using the Structure add-on, and have purchased Playa, Matrix and Stash as well.

Pages needed:
1. Product Category pages - displays links to Product Grid pages
2. Product Grid pages - displays product tiles. Tiles are groupings of products. The tiles must be created by the client in the CP because there are no patterns amongst the tile groupings.

*There is no singular product entry view. The Product Grids are the the most drilled down view of products.

Initially, I set up channels for Product Categories, Product Grids and Products. I related Product Grids to their respective Product Categories with Playa.

I imported a category of products as individual entries in the Products channel. This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure if my channel structure is the most efficient and I don't know how to most efficiently create the tiles. I feel like there has to be a better way.

Any thoughts on approach would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use EE categories for your product categories rather than channels. Each product tile is an entry in the products channel, and each tile is assigned to one or more categories which determines which product grid it shows up on. The index/category page is then just a list of the categories in your product categories group, and the product grid pages are essentially category archive pages showing all entries assigned to that category.

Comment: I'd agree. The client shouldn't even think about "tiles" - that's a design element that your templates will create. One channel & a category group is all that's needed here...clients just publish a product and select which categories it belongs to. Your EE templates will easily do the rest with native code.